# Количество чисел что имеют цифру "d" в своей записи

Tags: python, алгоритм, псевдокод

Кратко об условии и ограничениях,меня не интересует простейшая реализация,но если изменить решения с сайта https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-numbers-having-0-as-a-digit/ то буду благодарен)

> Дано число n,надо найти все такие числа от 1 до n что имеют цифру d(1..9) в своей записи.

```
Тест:
100 1
```

Числа что имеють единицу - (1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,100)

```
Вывод
20

Ограничения:
1<=n<=10^18
1<=d<=9

Час: 1 секунда
```

Comment: а чем простейшая реализация от иной отличается?

Comment: Сложность там цикл 1 до n и еще по длине каждого елемента не зайдёт в лимит 1 секунду.

Comment: в вопросе ничего нет про лимит

Comment: если коротко: `t = 100`, `r = 1` и `len(filter(lambda x: x>0, map(lambda x: (str(x)).count(str(r)), range(1, t + 1))))`, то `20`.
`

Comment: или сразу `t = 100`, `r = 1` и `len(filter(lambda x: (str(x)).count(str(r)) >0, range(1, t + 1)))` `python 2.7`

Comment: @EugeneDennis ``TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()``

Comment: для 3-его `filter` нужно обернуть в `list`, ну или что-то с методом `len`

Comment: Вопрос в чём - вывести все числа  (как в цветном тексте) или посчитать их количество (как в заголовке и на гиках)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто) на самом деле нужно считать число тех чисел которые *не содержат* данной. 
Так как d всегда не 0, для простоты добавим ведущие 0.

Пусть мы ищем ответ для числа a.
Перебираем первую цифру. 
Для всех цифр меньше (строго!) a[0] (старшей цифры) и если она не равна d добавим к ответу `9^(X-1)`. 
Теперь фиксируем первую цифру в a[0] (если не равно d), убираем первую фиру из числа и спускаемся на уровень ниже.

Осталось только вычесть.

**Пример**

12345 3.

Пошаговое.

```
1. 9^4 = 6561
2. 2*9^3 = 1458
3. 3*9^2 = 243
Дальше не надо, т.к. d = 3.
```

Итого ответ 12345 - (6561+1458+243-1) = 4084.

-1 надо т.к. способ считает 0 числом. Нужно его вычесть отдельно.

Лобовые циклы слишком медленные.

P.S. при d = 0 формулы меняются.

Comment: Несомненно, у Вас в голове решение сложилось (это видно по ключевым идеям). Но то, что написано - "сумбур вместо музыки" (c)

Comment: @MBo все ключевые идеи есть) дальше думаю самому интересно будет подумать тем, кто с таким не сталкивался. Задача явно учебная, поэтому детальные ответы как по мне не очень хорошо. Но вы можете написать свой или отредактировать этот.

Comment: Я писал такую же програмку,если зайдёт ваше решение то одобрю)

Comment: А что если дано число 99999 при цифре 3?Как ваш алгоритм будёт работать опишите подробнее

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets 1 шаг. от 0 до 8 без 3. `8*9^4` = 52488. 9 фиксированно. Дальше по анологии. `8*9^3`, `8*9^2`, `8*9`, `8`.  Сумма 59048. Ответ 40952.

Comment: def f(number,d):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0,len(number)):
        if int(number[i])<d:s+=int(number[i])*(9**(len(number)-i-1))
        else:s+=(int(number[i])-1)*(9**(len(number)-i-1))
    return int(number)-s
n,d = map(int,input().split())
n = str(n)
print(f(n,d))
Програма по вашему выдает ответ при 666 и 6  - 211,а как в то время правильный 181 :(

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets вы неправильно расписали случай когда `a[i] == d` тогда нужно остановить цикл и не добавлять.

Comment: Теперь все понятно)

Answer (score 0):

Верная идея у Eugene Dennis, но не нужно никаких фильтров. простой list comprehension:

```
rng, num=100, 1
len([x for x in range(1, rng + 1) if (str(x)).count(str(num))>0 ])
```

Output:

```
20
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что О(n) алгоритм успеет за 1 секунду просчитать до 10^18? Деталей не скажу, но это О(log n), т.е. нужно пробегать 0..9 по каждому разряду и для чисел 1..100 это займет всего 2*10+1 итерацию. Для 10^18 соответственно, всего 180 итераций.

Comment: Я просил никакого решения в лоб,не одобряю так как сам накатаю такой алгоритм за 5 секунд.